# How to list out only two specific format files in a folder and print it to a text file

Tags: perl

Below Codes is able to read only `txt` files and print out the `filename` and `size` into the `filename.txt`.

```
my $directory = 'c:\modules\SFTP';
my $file='filename.txt';
my $OUTFILE;

open $OUTFILE, '>>', $file;

my @files = do {
    opendir my $dh, $directory;
    grep {/^.*\.txt\z/si} readdir($dh);
};
foreach(@files){
 my $filesize = stat($_)->size;

  print { $OUTFILE } "$filesize $_" ,"\n";

}
```

My question is there anyway to read two specific file formats files instead of only one?

**Eg. Folder A**

```
textfile1.txt
textfile2.txt
testfile3.fcd
```

**Expected Result:**

Able to get and print out the `filename` and `size` for two specific formats `(.txt and .fcd)` files instead of only one `(.txt)`

What should I change or add in my code so I can get my expected result? Any related post or useful resources to share? Thanks!

Comment: `grep {/^.*\.(txt|fcd)\z/si}` should fix that.

Comment: @jaypal Hi, can you post the answer so I can accept it? =DD. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got most of it right. Make sure you have parens around `opendir`. `use warnings` should have pointed that out. Just add another pattern to your `grep`. Also, open your output file after you have read the directory other wise you will get your output file listed in the output.

```
use strict;
use warnings; 
use autodie;
use File::stat;

my $directory = 'c:\modules\SFTP';
my $file = 'filename.txt';

opendir (my $dh, $directory);
my @files = grep(/^.*\.(txt|fcd)\z/si, readdir $dh);

open my $OUTFILE, '>', $file;

foreach(@files){
    my $filesize = stat($_)->size;
    print $OUTFILE "$filesize $_" ,"\n";
}
```

Comment: The parens around the opendir arguments aren't necessary.

Comment: @JimDavis Right, but since there are two variables (file handle and directory) and `my $dh` is stated, it needs to be added. `use warnings` will show that. Alternatively, if you declare `$dh` before the `opendir` then yes, you don't need it then.

Comment: Interesting; it functions perfectly and presents no warnings on either Windows (Strawberry 5.20) or Ubuntu (5.10 & 5.18): `perl -Mstrict -wE 'my $foo = ".."; opendir my $df, $foo or die "$!"; say for readdir $df'`

Comment: @JimDavis Remove the `or die "$!"` and re-try. `:)`

Comment: Odd; according to Deparse -p, it boils down to `opendir(my $df, $foo)` with or without the `or die`.  (Reads more about it on [PerlMonks](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=917108))  It works, it just generates the warning because it *could* be ambiguous, but the `or die` makes it magically *not* ambiguous.  So it's really only *needed* to prevent the warning.

Comment: @JimDavis Yeah. I ran in to it while testing. After looking up for an explanation on-line, came across this [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/175231/970195). Thanks for the link to perlmonks.

Answer (score 1):

As has already been stated, all you need to filter based off more than one extension is to setup an alteration in  your regular expression:

```
/\.(?:txt|fcd)$/i
```

Note, that I've simplified your regex a little bit as well since it's not necessary to match against the beginning of the filename.

#### Enhancement by using Path::Class

I would like to recommend that you look into [`Path::Class`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Class) for easier file and path manipulation.

The following does the same thing as your script, but ensures you aren't missing path information in your file test:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

use Path::Class;

my $dir = dir('c:\modules\SFTP');

open my $outfh, '>>', 'filename.txt';

while (my $file = $dir->next) {
    next unless $file =~ /\.(?:txt|fcd)$/;
    printf $outfh "%s %s\n", $file->stat->size, $file->basename;
}
```